# Fatal Error cannot log into wordpress and website disappeared

Tags: php, cache, fatal-error

Hi i got a message to download another cache plugin but got another message saying the one i downloaded was not compatible with another plugin.  i tried to deactivate the plugin but it then threw me out of wordpress and my website disappeared. The message i get is this     Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /var/sites/c/carpetcleaningmorecambe.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1117.  Can someone help me please?

Comment: Go to your website hosting via cPanel or FTP and rename the plugin.

Comment: It might have corrupted something. - Try <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F">resetting the plugins folder</a> by <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients">FTP</a>. - If that does not help, then try <strong>MANUALLY</strong> updating. Please read the <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update">Manual Update</a> directions first.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin may have put a conditional file that desactivate the basic cache function of wordpress

to put them back, go in the `wp-content` repertory and rename the file `object-cache.php`